# How to initialize hook state . All state elements are missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There is something strange about this component's behavior

I tried to implement several ways.
but I still don't know how to initialize properly.

When this state

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
      qualification: props.profile.qualification,
      twitter: props.profile.twitter,
  });
```

RESULT
console.log("AA01" + JSON.stringify(state));
AA01{}
All elements are missing somehow.

So I Changed them like this

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    qualification: "",
    twitter: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      qualification: props.profile.qualification,
      twitter: props.profile.twitter,
    });
  });


const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log("AA01" + JSON.stringify(state));
  setState({ ...state, [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("AA" + JSON.stringify(state));
  if (state.userName.length < 2) {
    return;
  }
  props.Update(users);
};
```

The data of props are inserted to states but Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. happens

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: Just pass an empty dependency array like below

useEffect(() => {
  setState({
    qualification: props.profile.qualification,
    twitter: props.profile.twitter,
  });
}, []);

Answer (score 2):

Your `useEffect` hook is missing a dependency. Without one it runs every render and updates state and triggers another render.

Run once on component mount, use empty dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({
    qualification: props.profile.qualification,
    twitter: props.profile.twitter,
  });
}, []); // <-- run once on mount
```

Run when a value updates, use a populated dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({
    qualification: props.profile.qualification,
    twitter: props.profile.twitter,
  });
}, [value]); // <-- run when value updates
```

Don't use any state value that is updated unconditionally in the hook callback, this will also lead to render looping.

Sounds like you may want to update local state when the props update (they may also initially be empty like you've described), but this is *actually* an ***anti-pattern*** in React, you should consume the passed props directly.

**BUT**, if you still need to store them locally *for some reason* I think this is the implementation you seek:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({
    qualification: props.profile.qualification,
    twitter: props.profile.twitter,
  });
}, [props.profile]); // <-- run with props.profile updates
```